# Getting top terms per affinity propagation cluster in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, text-mining

I am trying different clustering methods for a bunch of news texts, and am struggling to find any way to find top terms per cluster for sklearns affinity propagation, and am becoming unsure if this is even possible.

For k-means clustering I am using the same approach as here: https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html
I would logically want to use the same X for affinity propagation as for k-means.

Anyone know how producing similar results with affinity propagation would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* compute the mean, and analyze it the same way as you did for k-means.

For maybe better results, you can weigh each document by the responsibility factor, if these are exposed by the sklearn API.